# Lists of corresponding values in servlet parameters

Tags: web-services, rest, servlets, parameters

When servlet parameters are repeated in a request, as in

```
city=London&city=Paris
```

a handler can get the array of String values for the `city` parameter.

Now imagine for each city I want the caller to also be able to provide the temperature. In other words, to provide an undetermined number of pairs of values. There needs to be a way for the caller to link the city with its temperature. I certainly don't want to count on any kind of implicit ordering, if even there is any:

```
city=London&city=Paris&temp=13&temp=15    # this can't be a good idea
```

Is there a preferred way to go about this? Or a well-explained "don't do that"?

I can think of various options. Combining city and temp in one param:

```
cityTemp=London,13&cityTemp=Paris,15
```

A dynamically named temp param for each provided city:

```
city=Paris&city=London&temp.Paris=15&temp.London=13
```

Corresponding lists in lieu of repeating the parameters:

```
cities=Paris,London&temps=15,13
```

And of course I could abandon simple name-value params altogether and have the caller post XML or JSON.

I can't say I love any of these solutions, but if one is more standard or has certain advantages that would be great to know. I haven't had any luck searching for this issue. I don't know if I'm not using the right terms, having a bad search day, or way off the mark in what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are not much parameters you have to bound, I would suggest you to go with comma separated parameter values which acts as key value pair.

```
cityTemp=London,13&cityTemp=Paris,15
```

This would ensure that you will get intended value with your key.

Comment: Thanks, Hardik, I tend to agree.  I'll go with that for now.